Github Actions is not deploying my serverless app correclty
I am working with Serverless Framework 4.4.0, and I am trying to deploy a Lambda in Typescript. Considering that Serverless since v.4 compiles typescript is not necessary to much configuration.
To give you more context I will share my serverless.yml
app: job-scraper-etl
service: job-scraper-etl

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: us-east-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  triggerStepFunction:
    handler: src/lambdas/triggerStepFunction.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 3 * * ? *) # Run every day at 3 am (UTC)
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - states:StartExecution
        Resource: arn:aws:states:${self:provider.region}:${aws:accountId}:stateMachine:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-JobScraper
    environment:
      STATE_MACHINE_ARN: arn:aws:states:${self:provider.region}:${aws:accountId}:stateMachine:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-JobScraper


plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function


my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

So, my problem is the next.
When I deploy my project using Github Action
# Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions
name: Deploy to AWS using Serverless Framework

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "18"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build TypeScript code
        run: npm run build

      - name: Deploy with Serverless
        run: npx serverless deploy
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY }}

and try to run my lambda, I received the next error
ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'triggerStepFunction'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'triggerStepFunction'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

which not happens when I run locally in my console.
npm run build
serverles deploy

I check AWS and the problem is in the .zip that I am creating.
When I run it manually in the console, the zip that I create looks like this

BUT, running the workflow by Github Actions, the zip that I create is different.

Changing the path in serverless by dist/... is not a solution.
So, Do you know if I am missing some configuration? I am not sure what I have to do to have the same result.
My serverless.yml already have the config
package:
  individually: true

to deploy each function individually.
Thank you so much!!!
